# Rails: Chaining several objects that are related in the build method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I am new to Ruby on Rails. I am trying to get my head around a fairly straightforward problem.

In my application, I have User, Micropost and Response models.

A User has many Microposts and has many responses. 
A Micropost has many responses
A response belongs to a User and a Micropost.

Simple enough.

In my app I have the current user defined as current_user.

Here are my related routes.

```
 resources :users

 resources :microposts do

   resources :responses

 end
```

Here is a form on the micropost "show" view.....i.e a response to the micropost.

```
        <%= form_for([@micropost, @response]) do |f| %>
        <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>
        <div class="field">
          <%= f.text_area :content, placeholder: "Do you have an answer?",  :style => "height:75px;" %>
        </div>
        <%= f.submit "Answer this question", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
```

Here is the create method in the response controller

```
  def create
      @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
      @response = @micorpost.responses.build(response_params)
      respond_to do |format|
      if @response.save
         format.html { redirect_to root_url, notice: 'Response was successfully created.' }
         format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @response }
      else
         format.html { render :new }
         format.json { render json: @response.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

The issue is this -

How do I get the user id into this create method?

Is there a way to chain two objects in the build method....i.e. something like

```
  @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
  @response = current_user.microposts.responses.build(response_params)
```

This obviously does not work as it is.

I am trying to learn the correct way - using the relationship definitions to get this right and given the general awesomeness of Rails so far, I am sure there is a very easy answer to this - there are plenty of answers when you have just two models that are related, but I can't seem to find one that addresses this situation where you have 3.

(Also I created the response controller in scaffold as you can see which is perhaps not a good way for a beginner to do this)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of any way to use `build` to make an object with two associations in one swoop.

Since you are already using `build` and `save` instead of create, the easiest way might be to set the responses' user explicitely:

```
@response = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id]).responses.build(response_params)
@response.user = current_user

if @response.save …
```

It's not clever, but explicit and readable.

Comment: Cheers for the response, but the responses need to belong to the user.........a user may have a response to a micropost that is not their own. By your schema, the micropost user_id is assumed to then be the user associated any response to that micropost. Correct me if I have misunderstood you.

Comment: @GhostRider gotcha! Sorry for the misunderstanding. I've updated the answer.

Comment: This works, but is there a clever "rails" way to do this? See the answer by Nafaa below - is there a way of getting at this is the mass assignment of parameters....

Comment: I'd say this _is_ the "Rails" way of doing it - you'll find this pattern all over the place. For me, "clever" is code I can understand six months from now without thinking twice.

Answer (score 0):

Simply do this

```
 response_params = response_params.merge({user_id: current_user.id, micropost_id: params[:micropost_id]}
 Response.create(respone_params))
```

Comment: Oh, excuse me obviously I meant `params[:micropost_id]` and not `:micropost_id`, because I tested it on a test project before I posted it and It worked very well. I think this is better than the selected answer, because It does not make unnecessary request to the database to retrieve the  `@micropost`.

Comment: About readability, I don't see it non readable. but instead very concise and clear.